# A list of sliding windows over a list

Tags: python, slice

I have a list of length `L`

```
In [92]: li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and I know how I can generate `N` overlapping sub-lists

```
In [93]: L, N = 10, 4                                                                     

In [94]: [li[i:L-N+1+i] for i in range(N)]                                                
Out[94]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

On the other hand I don't know how to obtain the same result without using `L`

```
In [95]: [li[i:i-N+1] for i in range(N)]                                                  
Out[95]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], []]
```

short of using `i-N+1 if i-N+1 else None` as the second part of the slice specification.

Is it possible to obtain my list of sub-lists w/o using `L` and w/o a conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheeky boolean abuse:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 4
lsts = [li[i:(i-N+1 or None)] for i in range(N)]
print(*lsts, sep='\n')
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Wrt my `... if ... else None` this is way better, 1st the conditional is cleverly disguised and 2nd the expression is evaluated exactly `N` times.

Comment: @gboffi In Python 3.8, with an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) you could write `lsts = [li[i:(j if (j:=i-N+1) else None)] for i in range(N)]`

Comment: I prefer the answer's solution to the one in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this would be a workaround:

```
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> N = 4
>>> [(li+[''])[i:i-N] for i in range(N)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This is tricky without being able to use the length of the list!

Comment: It works but it's really inefficient, because you create and immediately throw away `N` lists of length `L+1` and in a real size problem this could be a problem.

Comment: `[liplus[i:i-N] for liplus in[li+['']] for i in range(N)]` is unreadable but reuses a single extended list

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 4

b = np.tile(li, N+1)[:N*(len(li)+1)].reshape(N, len(li)+1)[:,:-N]
print(b)
```

results in

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10]]
```